# Request header field X-Requested

Tags: xmlhttprequest, cors, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, preflight

I am trying to access a file in a bucket on google cloud storage. I have set the CORS configuration for the bucket. But I am getting this error when I make a request across https://. It works fine for requests made across http://.

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load "FILENAME".

Request header field X-Requested-With is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must include `X-Requested-With` in the value of the `responseHeader` member in your config:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://example.appspot.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["X-Requested-With"],
      "method": ["GET", "POST"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

See [the relevant docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin), which say:

> If this is a preflight request, check if the preflight request includes one or more `Access-Control-Request-Header`. If so, then ensure that the matching CORS configuration entry includes a `<ResponseHeader>` entry for each requested header. All headers named in the `Access-Control-Request-Header` must be in the CORS configuration for the preflight request to succeed and include CORS headers in the response.